# Where can I find defined colors in android

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design

I've created the project from default template Bottom Navigation Activity. I found that the background color for `BottomNavigationView` is `#2D2D2D` for dark theme. I defined it in `colors.xml`, but I'm not sure that it's good solution. Is there any pre-defined colors in system(smth like `@android:color/theColorThatINeed`)? Where can I see all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a single place to find all the 'system colours'. You can either find them through documentation, which is usually easy with the material components (which is where `BottomNavigationView` is from), or by trawling through the source code. For your particular example the colour you're after is `?attr/colorSurface`, which is in the [documentation](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/android#bottom-navigation-bar) and the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/res/values/styles.xml).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice that there is answer in documentation!

Answer (score 1):

the best practice is to use colors.xml, and put there all of your colors,
and then call it like this:

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

there are also system constants for colors, which contains this constants:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

this resources are read only and you can not add to them more constants.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any pre-defined colors in system?

Yes, there is but it's  limited. These colors are defined in [**android.R.color**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color). Here are some of them.

```
background_dark
background_light
black
darker_gray
holo_blue_bright
holo_blue_dark
holo_blue_light
holo_green_dark
holo_green_light
holo_orange_dark
holo_orange_light
holo_purple
holo_red_dark
holo_red_light
transparent
white
widget_edittext_dark
```

To use them:

```xml
android:background="@android:color/background_dark"/>
```