# How to modify androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android, html

I have made an application by converting my web app to android app, these pink buttons are showing, how can I change this button's color ?
[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGhiW.jpg)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwrSV.jpg)

I have tried by viewing androidmanifest.xml

Comment: check out Styles and themes doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes), get familiar with this mechanism and pick fitting answer in previously asked question about same problem

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, but you can try this:

Try to find this color in the resources directory and modify it

Also you can see answers for this question:

[Where can I find defined colors in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69704056/where-can-i-find-defined-colors-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I just founded the colors.xml file and I replaced colorAccent with my custom color

Comment: if that helped you, please like comment and mark the answer as solved